# Flutter Firebase Auth Login logs firing off without user logging In

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

Like the title says, I'm seeing weird logs when my app is running.
The first one I get is

```
W/BiChannelGoogleApi( 3072): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@36d7eba
W/DynamiteModule( 3072): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth( 3072): [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
I/FirebaseAuth( 3072): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
D/FirebaseAuth( 3072): Notifying id token listeners about user ( *useridhere* ).
D/FirebaseApp( 3072): Notifying auth state listeners.
D/FirebaseApp( 3072): Notified 1 auth state listeners.
```

And then a little Later I get

```
I/FirebaseAuth( 3072): [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
I/FirebaseAuth( 3072): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
```

This is amid all of my normal logs that I would expect, so I'm curious if this could be causing any problems? It sure doesn't seem right.

EDIT:

Just to be clear, after immediately logging in I get

```
W/DynamiteModule( 3072): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/BiChannelGoogleApi( 3072): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@36d7eba
W/DynamiteModule( 3072): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth( 3072): [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
I/FirebaseAuth( 3072): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
D/FirebaseAuth( 3072): Notifying id token listeners about user ( *useridhere*).
D/FirebaseAuth( 3072): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( *useridhere* ).
D/FirebaseApp( 3072): Notifying auth state listeners.
D/FirebaseApp( 3072): Notified 1 auth state listeners.
```

Which I know is normal. However, this happens in the middle of the app running, which does NOT seem normal

Comment: Based on the logs and knowledge of the system, I wrote an explanation below. If that doesn't help (enough) update your question to include the minimal code that is needed to reproduce the behavior. For more on how and why to do this, see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start an app that uses Firebase Authentication, it automatically tries to reauthenticate the user that was logged in before. In this case it also seems like there is one listener to auth state changes (that could be FlutterFire itself), which the Firebase Authentication client then informs of the authentication state.

Comment: Please check my updated post, I know that that is normal to have it log that on logging in, but it logs it again way after the user has logged in

Comment: The ID token of the user is refreshed occasionally (every 55 minutes or so), which I'd expect to log information too.

Comment: I found more information [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions), thanks this is it